# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate is showing every time blew is my full code

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

friends plz check-am using **PHPMailer** but not send my mail all ready am use before use this but this time not working.

> error SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

**Code:**

```
require_once"phphmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

[TWO-STEP VERIFICATION IS ALREADY OFF, Less secure app access IS ALSO ON, PLZ CHECK THIS LINK][1]

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->setFrom('Quantikitfoods@gmail.com','QuantiKit');
    $mail->addAddress('jawedroyalkhan@gmil.com','QuantiKit');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message1;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mail->Username = 'jawedroyalkhan@gmil.com';
    $mail->Password = 'is only alphabet my password';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

http://www.bhupatiengineering.com/phpmailer/contact.php

Comment: Most likely an SMTP redirect by your hosting provider, but it may be one of gmail's annoyances too. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, and post your debug output in your question.

Comment: Ok,but am using GoDaddy,bluehost both r same problem

Comment: Both are known for doing exactly this, so **post your debug output**. I can't help you if you don't provide sufficient info. and again **read the troubleshooting guide** because it covers this exact situation.

Comment: Is there a typo at `jawedroyalkhan@gmil.com`? Shouldn't it be gmail?

Comment: Am checking thanks.will update u

Comment: am created right @gmail.com but showing  error       *SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.* synchro

Comment: Also please  provide right code if u have plz